# Method to solve an equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, diophantine-equations

The question is: put one of $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ in one position below, to obtain $100$
$$\large\overline{\square\square}+\overline{\square\square}+\overline{\square\square}=100$$his mean fint
This mean to find three,two digit number with sum of 100.
I can find by guess and exam some of the possible answer like below
$$45+37+18=100\\
46+35+19=100\\65+23+12=100
$$ But I am looking for a $\large\text {method}$ to solve the equation.
AS a second question, how to find all the possibilities? (when do not repeat any number)
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: $45+3+18=100$ must be a typo. $3$ should be $37$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: yes I missed 7 when i was typing. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to solve

$$(10a+b)+(10c+d)+(10e+f)=100 \implies 10(a+c+e)+b+d+f=100$$

and we have two cases

- $b+d+f=10 \implies a+c+e=9$
- $b+d+f=20 \implies a+c+e=8$

Comment: @Christoph Yes it was symbolic! I've fixed that.

Comment: it's ok ,but how can find the possible ways of the solution?

Comment: Since it says not to repeat any number, we can rule out $b+d+f=0$.

Comment: @Khosrotash For any triple $b,d,f$ such that $b+d+f=0$ or $=10$ or $=20$ we can find $a,c,e$ such that $a+c+e=10$ or $=9$ or $=8$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes thanks I lost this condition! Fixed

Comment: @Khosrotash The method is to solve at first $b+d+f=10 $ and then $a+c+e=9$ or  $b+d+f=20 $ and then $a+c+e=8$, nothing else.